# preg_match pattern variable usage

Tags: php, regex, variables

I tried searching here and Google, but couldn't find a solution to the following:

```
$picUrl = '"thumbs/phpThumb.php?src=../property-photos/50/2485/068cf6589a9fb13065818efef3d1e1c0-small.jpg&w=80&h=60&far=1&bg=EEEEEE"';
$number = "2485";
$expression = "'#".$number."/(.*?)&w#'";
echo "<b>expression is </b>".$expression."<br />";
echo "<b>picUrl is </b>".$picUrl."<br />";
preg_match($expression, $picUrl, $pic);  //'#2485/(.*?)&w#'
//if($pic) echo "pic is ".$pic[1]."<br />";
echo "<b>contents of pic array</b>".var_dump($pic);
```

As written above, the array is empty. However, if I replace the `$expression` variable in the `preg_match` function, with the text following the php comment (ie: `'#2485/(.*?)&w#'`), I get the desired result.

Why is the use of the $expression variable not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$expression` is a string starting with and ending with `'`. Thus, `'` becomes the delimiter, and `#` becomes a literal in your regex. `'#2485/(.*?)&w#'` is a string starting and ending with `#` which now is a delimiter of the regex and not a literal.

Simply use either this:

```
$expression = "#".$number."/(.*?)&w#";
```

or (which I recommend) this:

```
$expression = '#'.$number.'/(.*?)&w#';
```

Comment: Duh! Thanks alot. I've been staring at my screen for 5 days solid :). I'll use your recommendation as I only used double quotes in the original because of the double quote needed to escape the $number variable. I've been right round the houses trying to figure this one out and it was so simple all along! That's how the cookie crumbles sometimes, eh?

Answer (score 0):

Remove single quotes from your `$expression`:

```
$expression = "#".$number."/(.*?)&w#";
```

Comment: Why not: "#{$number}/(.*?)&w#"; ? You already have double quotes and PHP expands variables in them. Why concatenate? Same goes for @m. buettner.

Comment: Could be as well. But maybe even better would be to use only single quotes and concatenate as m.buettner pointed out. Then php doesn't have to expand variables inside a string.

Comment: Does not expand but concatenates. No win. You have 1 expand vs. 2 concatenations.